# How to call different hosts at runtime in spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-bean

An API should call a different host at runtime based on the env variable from the request header

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is basically you need dynamic routing based on the type of request headers & ENV variables. You can checkout this article which could be useful for you.

[Example of dynamic routing Spring Cloud Gateway](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway)